# Method of characteristics in hyperbolic PDE's

Tags: hyperbolic-equations

I was reading Hyperbolic Partial Differential equations and its solutions through the method of characteristic. It stated that to find the solution, you need the characteristics $f$ and $g$ to intersect and at that point, you calculate the value. My question is how is it assumed that the characteristics will intersect? What if they don't?

The characteristics are $y'=f $ and $y'=g$ Can somebody help

Comment: Perhaps you could say what the PDE you are trying to solve is and how you got the equations for the characteristics from the PDE.

Comment: $a(x,y,u)u_{tt}+b(x,y,u)u_{xy}+c(x,y,u)u_{xx}=0$

Comment: The method of characteristics works only for first order PDE You can apply it to a second order PDE, if you can factor the differential operator into a composition of two first order operators. Also, your question is phrased a bit too vaguely. Could you provide more details on what the book says about solving a second order PDE using the method of characteristics?

Comment: I guess it also works for hyperbolic pde of second order.